# Rails : gmaps4rails map does not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, maps

I am aware there are many questions on this topic, however non work for me for some reason.
I have installed gmaps4rails gem (up to date). 
I have followed all the instructions and have included all the necessary files for it to work.
Everything is fine, however the only problem is that the actual map does not load/render?

This is my layout page:

> ```
>   <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>Mash's Wing Ranch&reg; | <%= @page_title || 'Admin Area' %></title>
>         <%= stylesheet_link_tag('admin_main', :media => 'all') %>
>         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "gmaps4rails" %>
>         <%= javascript_include_tag ('gmaps4rails.base','gmaps4rails.bing','gmaps4rails.googlemaps','gmaps4rails.mapquest','gmaps4railsopenlayers') %>   
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <div id="headercontainer">
>             <div id="headercontent">
>                 <div id="headerlogo"></div>
>                 <div id="headernavigation">
>                     <ul>
>                         <li><%= link_to("Users", {:controller => 'admin_users', :action => 'list'}) %></li>
>                         <li><%= link_to("Menu", {:controller => 'menus', :action => 'list'}) %></li>
>                         <li><%= link_to("Sauces", {:controller => 'sauces', :action => 'list'}) %></li>
>                         <li><%= link_to("Ranches", {:controller => 'ranches', :action => 'list'}) %></li>
>                         <li><%= link_to("Franchise", {:controller => 'franchises', :action => 'list'}) %></li>
>                         <li><%= link_to("Mailing List", {:controller => 'mailing_lists', :action => 'list'}) %></li>
>                     </ul>
>                 </div>
>                 <div id="headerinformation">
>                     <p>Admin Area</p>
>                     <p><%= Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></p>
>                     <p><%= Time.now.strftime("%I:%M%p") %></p>
>                     <p>User - <%= session[:first_name] %> <%= session[:last_name] %></p>
>                     <p><%= link_to("Log Out", :controller => 'access', :action => 'logout') %></p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <div id="pagetitlecontainer">
>             <div id="pagetitlecontent">
>                 <h3><%= @pagetitle %></h3>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
>         <div id="noticecontainer">
>             <div id="noticecontent">
>                 <h4 class="notice">
>                 <%= flash[:notice] %>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <% end %>
>         <% if !flash[:error].blank? %>
>         <div id="errornoticecontainer">
>             <div id="errornoticecontent">
>                 <h4 class="notice">
>                 <%= flash[:error] %>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>         <% end %>
>         <div id="contentcontainer">
>             <div id="content"><%= yield %></div>
>         </div>
>         <div id="footercontainer">
>             <div id="footercontent">
>                 <p>Mash's Wing Ranch&reg; All Rights Reserved 2012</p>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     <%= yield :scripts %>
>     </body>
>     </html>
> ```

I have also added the `<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>` in my view.

Comment: Can you post your model that you wish to be gmapable? Did you run the migrations that are required on your model?

Comment: I think the problem is because when i do `javascript_include_tag('name')` it renders as `name.js` and all the google maps js are `js.coffee` how do I add the `.coffee` at the end?

Comment: What you should have is all of the files you need listed in your application.js folder without the extensions on them and rails will add them properly when you `javascript_include_tag('application')` Same with the way you're doing it currently, it'll automatically convert them for you. You can check this by viewing source and seeing if the .js files are included, click the file and see if its converted to javascript.